# Using Random object to generate colors

Tags: c#

I've got a vey simple form with a grid of 16 labels, each of which I wish to set the Background color at random from 12 colors I have chosen.

Here is my code:

```
private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtA1.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtA2.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtA3.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtA4.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtB1.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtB2.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtB3.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtB4.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtC1.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtC2.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtC3.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtC4.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtD1.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtD2.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtD3.BackColor = RandomColor();
        txtD4.BackColor = RandomColor();
    }

    private Color RandomColor()
    {            
        Random rand = new Random();
        int r = rand.Next(1, 12);
        switch (r)
        {
            case 1:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.DodgerBlue);
            case 2:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.MediumAquamarine);
            case 3:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Teal);
            case 4:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.OrangeRed);
            case 5:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.LightCoral);
            case 6:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Red);
            case 7:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.MediumOrchid);
            case 8:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.MediumPurple);
            case 9:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.DarkOrchid);
            case 10:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Lime);
            case 11:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.PaleGreen);
            case 12:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.SeaGreen);
            default:
                return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.White);
        }
    }
```

But what is happening is that ALL 16 labels are assigned the same backcolor, rather than each being randomized individually.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Probable cause of the issue**

It because you are creating `Random` object each time the `RandomColor()` method is called and call it few times almost at the same time.

**Explanation**

When you write `new Random();` the pseudorandom function is initiated with a seed based on a current time. Seed is a value that determines the values returned by the `Random` object (values of pseudorandom function). This means that when you create two `Random` objects with the same seed, they return the same values in the subsequent `Next()` method.

In your case you are calling the method few times, so the seed may be the same and that's why it returns the same value for all the labels.

**Suggested solution**

In order to fix it, move `Random rand = new Random();` outside the method, to be created only once for a class instance.

Answer (score 0):

"If you used a new Random() at the method level as a local time-dependent seed would repeat itself." [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/random)
Use static variable in class for Random:

```
private static Random rand = new Random();

private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code here
    }

    private Color RandomColor()
    {
        int r = rand.Next(1, 12);
        //switch here
        return Color.White;
    }
```

Comment: @Magnus really? don't know, use like that everywhere. Thanks

Comment: If accessed from multiple threads after some time it gets corrupted and starts returning only zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that

```
static Random _r = new Random();
    static void F()
    {
    int n = _r.Next(5);
    // Can return 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4
    Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
```

great page on random http://www.dotnetperls.com/random